# Visual Studio Community 2017 on Mac: How to view same file in two columns?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-2017

I want to view different portions of the same C# code file in two separate columns side by side (horizontal split of the editor).  I can put the editor in two column mode, but I can't find a way to view the file simultaneously in both columns.

Related solutions that I've found by searching seem to be for previous versions of Visual Studio.  They reference menu options like Window -> New Window that aren't present for me in VS 2017.

Is there no way to view different portions of the same file in two columns in Visual Studio 2017?

[image: What my window menu looks like]

Comment: I use VsVim,  if you use that, then you can just do `:vsp`      and you get what you want.   Only trick is, you need to learn Vim.... but the side effect is you become much more awesome at manipulating code :)

Comment: Also, not sure why they aren't present... I have VS2017 and they are all there

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: No, I never solved the problem.  I think the mac version is just lacking this functionality.

Comment: +1 that feature would be really useful for big source files. In XCode you can see the same file side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mac version is just lacking this functionality.